# PyCharm always thows this error on creating new project and interpreter(virtual env) is missing for the project

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have got a problem with pycharm. I reinstalled everything(system python, anaconda, pycharm) since I thought it was conflicting with Anaconda. Finally, I completely got rid of Anaconda and still Pycharm throws the following error whenever I create a new project.

```
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\Ritanshu Singh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe 
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 
2018.3.2\helpers\packaging_tool.py" list'
```

Also the project(virtual env) interpreter is missing every time I create a new project(My actual system python is installed and works well, I have tried and run a raw python text file) and I can't run the python code. I googled but it shows no results.

I figured out that it has a problem to create virtual environment interpreter but I don't know why? The error code is above listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very good documentation available for configuring the python interpreter in Pycharm: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html and
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html

Please verify that you follow these steps before starting the Pycharm.

- Do not import config.
- Check the user permission which starts the Pycharm(Administrative).
- Add path variable for **python** in windows.
- install and configure the **pip** that will help you to download the package while setting up the interpreter.

Comment: I do follow all steps and try to create new virtual env and it throws the same error. There is any technical error going on here. Everything works well with the system interpretor but I don't want to disturb the libraries of system and want to create a virtual env

Answer (score 0):

I found that from Python version 3.3+, the built-in venv module is used, instead of the third-party virtualenv utility. It is written on PyCharm Official Page on this link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html